# On using "=" on arrays in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, variables, data-structures

I just start to learn python, and today I stumble upon a behavior which I could not understand about python and its array, or maybe how python treat its variable, in this case arrays.

Here is the code that I have:

```
 some_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 x = some_array
 x[2] = 10
 print(some_array)
 print(x)
```

Here is the output I got.

```
[1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here even though I changed only the third element of *x*, the initial *some_array* is also affected, which I really don't understand. It looks like to me, by using the instruction *x = some_array*, *x* and *some_array* then point to the same address space, therefore the behavior. Could someone please explain me this? And what should I do to avoid this situation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assignment in python does not create copies.  Assignment associates a name to a value.

Comment: read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html